# get string value with firebug console

Tags: jquery, console

I have a rather lengthy form that builds selected options into an xml string for submission to a third party. I have had to make some changes and want to make sure they are correct. How do I check the value of the string as it's being built in console? I've tried:

`console.log; $("#StringName").val();`

but it just returns undefined. Is there a way that will work? 
thx

Comment: `console.log($("#StringName").val());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`console.log($("#StringName").val());` should work

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it. Admittedly I'm an idiot with console...any advice on where to learn from? thx again.